# VialerPJSIP PJSIP The 'Pods- ' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries:

Tags: cocoapods, sip, pjsip, transitive-dependency

I'm trying to install an objective-c Wrapper for Jsip 'VialerSIPLib' and use it in my Swift project here is my pod getting the error:

> The 'Pods- ' target has transitive dependencies that include
>   statically linked binaries: (/Users/apple/Desktop/PJSIP
>   NEW/VialerSIPLib/Example/Pods/Vialer-pjsip-iOS/VialerPJSIP.framework)

Can anyone help to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove or comment out use_frameworks! in your podfile